# Reshaping the dimension of a tensor in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

There is a tensor with the shape of `[b, nt*nh*nw, dim]`. The values of nt, nh, and nw are in hand. How can I reshape this tensor to the form of [b, dim, nt, nh, nw]? For example, how it is possible to reshape [2, 3x2x4, 512] to [2,512,3,2,4]?

Comment: Your shapes don't match. In your example, nt, nh, nw = 3, 2, 4. Multiply them gives you 24 not 324. I'm assuming you meant that, if so, why can't you use data.reshape(b, nt\*nh\*nw, dim)?

Comment: @IM , That was typo. it is corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on your data layout in memory.

However, assuming `nt`, `nh`, and `nw` are in the correct ordering in your underlying data tensor then you can do so by permuting and reshaping your tensor.

First swap dimensions to place `dim` as the 2nd axis using [`torch.transpose`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.transpose.html) or [`torch.permute`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.permute.html). Then reshape the tensor to the desired shape with [`torch.view`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.view.html) or [`torch.reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.reshape.html):

```
>>> x.transpose(1,2).view(b, dim, nt, nh, nw)
```